# Read annotation of generic class Java

Tags: java, generics, annotations

I had an idea to use a Dao class (Dao.java):

```
class Dao <Model extends AbstractModel> {
    public String getUrl() {
        return Model.class.getAnnotation(MyPath.class).url();
    }
}
```

and a model like this (Account.java):

```
@MyPath(url = "blabla")
class Account extends AbstractModel {
    ...
}
```

but the problem is that in that case if i run

```
@Test
public void testDaoUrl() {
    Dao<Account> dao = new Dao<Account>();
    dao.getUrl();
}
```

Model.class seems to be an AbstractModel and not an Account. **Is there any work around to get MyPath annotation from the Dao (without giving it an instance of Account.class)?**

Thanks in advance for any idea!

PS: MyPath-Annotation:

```
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Target(TYPE)
@interface MyPath {
    public String url();
}
```

Comment: `Model.class` should be a compiler error. Also, possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there is another solution, but it's uglier than passing a `Class` argument to the `Dao` constructor and more prone to error.

This trick is known as the [type token](http://gafter.blogspot.com/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html). I've seen it used mostly in deserialization libraries (like Gson or Jackson for JSON).

```
class Dao<Model extends AbstractModel> {
    private final Class<?> typeArgument;

    public Dao() {
        Type superclass = getClass().getGenericSuperclass(); 
        ParameterizedType parameterized = (ParameterizedType) superclass;
        // with nested generic types, this becomes a little more complicated
        typeArgument = (Class<?>) parameterized.getActualTypeArguments()[0];
    }

    public String getUrl() {
        return typeArgument.getAnnotation(MyPath.class).url();
    }
}
```

and used like so

```
new Dao<Account>(){}.getUrl()
```

So, when creating a `Dao` instance, you actually, instead, create a `Dao` subclass instance. This way the instance is of a parameterized subtype of `Dao`, ie. something like

```
class AnonymousDao extends Dao<Account> {}
```

and then the parameterized type can be extracted and used.